# Running program multiple times using batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a program I wrote that I need to run multiple times. I tried writing a batch script to do this but it's not working correctly.

I tried using

```
@echo off
start polymer.exe
start polymer.exe
```

and also tried

```
@echo off
for /l %%X in (1,1,2) do (start polymer.exe)
```

polymer.exe writes a number out to a file every time it is run and very rarely will 2 numbers be identical but when I run these scripts I get two identical numbers in the output. Any ideas why this is happening?

OS is Windows 7

Comment: What happens if you put a "sleep 5" between each one?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forget to initialize your random number generator.

```
C : srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)));

C# : Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Comment: I'm quite new to this stuff so I'm not exactly sure what you mean but I'm using a random number generator function written by my prof and am using time_t to seed the generator function. If I run polymer.exe consecutively manually the outputs are different, if that's relevent info

Answer (score 0):

If your exe generates a random number based on the time, and you can't modify it, you can insert a pause statement in the batch script between the calls.

You can emulate a wait like this (will pause 3 seconds):

```
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 4
```

Comment: that appears to be working, thanks    edit - can you tell me how to put that in the for loop?

Comment: I got it in the for loop using a second batch file, thanks guys